# find command can't exclude the exact regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
arg=$1
exclude='(/etc/alternatives/(awk|vim)|/usr/sbin/poweroff)$'
find $arg -type f,l,c,b -regextype posix-extended -not -regex "${exclude}" -print
```

I haven't used `^` at the beginning of each file so it could be started with anything. But I have used `$` at the end of each file.

So when I run the script this way it is working properly:

```
$ sudo bash script.sh /etc/ | grep awk
/etc/alternatives/nawk
/etc/alternatives/nawk.1.gz
/etc/alternatives/awk.1.gz
```

But When I do that is faults:

```
$ sudo cp -rv /etc/ /tmp/
$ sudo bash script.sh /tmp/etc/ | grep awk
/tmp/etc/alternatives/awk
/tmp/etc/alternatives/nawk
/tmp/etc/alternatives/nawk.1.gz
/tmp/etc/alternatives/awk.1.gz
```

Here you see file `/tmp/etc/alternatives/awk` that shouldn't be passed at the result because of lacking `^` sign.

## Update

This pattern is working nice but I want to use above one:

```
find $arg -type f,l,c,b | grep -Ev "${exclude}"
```

Comment: Try changing the -regextype from postix-extended to posix-egrep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the `-regex` test is a feature specific to GNU's implementation of `find`; it is not defined by POSIX.  GNU's implementation is anyway almost certainly the one you will find on your favorite Linux distribution.  [Its manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002dregex) has this to say:

> Test: -regex expr
>  Test: -iregex expr
>  True if the entire file
> name matches regular expression expr. **This is a match on the whole
> path, not a search**. [...]

(emphasis added).  That is, the test is always performed as if the regex were anchored to the beginning end end of the line, even if there are no explicit anchors in the pattern.  You can work around that by prefixing and / or suffixing your regex with `.*`, as appropriate.

For your example, that might look like so:

```
exclude='.*(/etc/alternatives/(awk|vim)|/usr/sbin/poweroff)'
```

I have omitted the unneeded trailing anchor because that seems clearer to me, but if you prefer to retain it then do so -- it is not harmful.

Comment: Thank you. it is working. which method is better? `grep -Ev "${exclude}"
` or `-regextype posix-extended -not -regex "${exclude}" -print`?

Comment: @M.J, rhe `grep` version is more portable, but if you only care about supporting systems that have GNU `find` then it's lighter weight to do the job with one process, via `-regex`, than with a two-process pipeline.

Comment: But when your script is in `/tmp` and you want to run the script this way:`bash script.sh etc/` it isn't working and always you have to use absolute path for argument.

Comment: @M.J, the paths that `find` matches against the regex are the same ones that it ultimately prints.  These start with the starting-point directory names that are specified to it.  I take the question to be about the semantics of (GNU) `find`'s `-regex` test, and that's what I have answered.  My recommendation does the job for the examples presented in the question.  If you need help tweaking the regex to serve more cases then that would be a subject for a different question.

Comment: So we need to use `realpath` command to get file absolute path the process it. Thank you.